# Losing cell reference on update

Tags: excel

I have a formula that normally works well referencing `REPORT!S:S`however, when I update my data which includes deleting/refreshing cell data my reference to `REPORT!S:S`gives an error of `REPORT!#REF!`. Can anyone provide a solution so that I can keep my cell reference even after I have updated my column S:S. Thank you!

```
=INDEX(REPORT!A:CR,MATCH(CONCATENATE($C$21,$C$23,$C$26,$C$27),REPORT!S:S,0),34)

=INDEX(REPORT!A:CR,MATCH(CONCATENATE($C$21,$C$23,$C$26,$C$27),REPORT!#REF!,0),34)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "Clear Contents" on `Column S` as opposed to deleting the data.

Doing so should maintain your reference and keep it from erring out.